# Difference between OpenSG and OpenSceneGraph

Tags: openscenegraph, opensg

First of all I read the offcial comparison [OpenSG](http://www.opensg.org/projects/opensg) and [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.com/index.php/support/faq#IhavenoideawhatOpenSceneGraphiscanyougivemeashortdescription). My current goal is to create a small game engine for learning purpose. I started with pure OpenGL but then I found those scene graph libraries which are looking quite nice.

I would like to know the differences between those two scene graphs. Their comparison was very vague. For example OSG stated that OpenSG is probably better in multithreading.

OpenSG stated and I quote

> OpenScenegraph leaned heavily on the Performer side of things in the
>   beginning ....  OpenSG leaned more on the Fahrenheit side... These
>   days, in your self-interest, you should be using an Open Source system
>   like OpenSG.

I would like to know the difference between OpenSG and OpenSceneGraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to define, for those not versed in SceneGraph lore.

OpenSG has some more clever multithreading features that OpenSceneGraph lacks. However, OpenSceneGraph seems to make up for it with a much larger and more vibrant community, and more extensive derivative and add-on tools.

I chose OpenSceneGraph myself nearly ten years ago and have not regretted the decision.

You might also consider more high-level game tools like OGRE, which might be more in line with what you want than either OpenSG or OSG.